# SQL query or algorithm for transaction process in different supplier

Tags: php, sql

I'm having trouble with my query because I have to deduct the quantity of the product from a different supplier.

Let say I have 2 suppliers with the same product, each supplier has a stock of 5 quantities. The customer wants to buy 7 products. How can I subtract the first 5 stock quantities in the first supplier and subtract the 2 stock quantities in the second supplier? What should I do in the SQL query and PHP? THANK YOU this is my table.

The customer will buy 7 shirts, and we have 10 total shirts. please help in fetching this data in SQL using PHP.

First, the 5 shirts will deduct in Supplier A and the next 2 shirts will deduct in Supplier B. please help me or give me some insight to query this in SQL using PHP. Thank You!

```
Supplier      Product       Quantity         Date Inserted
   A           shirt           5               01/01/2019
   B           shirt           5               01/29/2019
```

Comment: Please show your expected output

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without output sample, I suspect your need something like this [fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=87a12490eca54acf8f5957ab2b34472a):

```
 select * from(
        select Supplier, Product,DateInserted, Quantity OldQuantity
        ,case when cumulsum <= TotalRequiredQuantity  then 0 else cumulsum-TotalRequiredQuantity end  NewQuantity 
         from(
           select *, 7 TotalRequiredQuantity, /*Set required value here*/
              sum(quantity) over(partition by Product order by DateInserted) cumulsum
           from yourTable
        )q
    )q1
    where OldQuantity>=NewQuantity;
```

Comment: Thanks bro your awesome! Im going to try this.

Comment: @arbispo , please accept if this answers your question.

Comment: @Grigory Frolov, Sir, this is my another problem https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60576264/query-for-update-stock-quantity-in-transaction