# Query for update stock quantity in transaction

Tags: php, mysql, database, web

I'm having trouble with my query because I have to deduct the quantity of the product from a different stock_code.

Let say the customer will buy a product in item_code (I0015) for 20 quantities. First I want to deduct the 12 quantities to the stock_code (ST0016) and the stock will become 0, and the remaining 8 quantities will deduct in stock_code (ST0012), the deduction of quantity is based on the ascending date of stock_expired.

How do I query that in MySQL? Thank you so much! The answer is highly appreciated. The name of my table is stocks_table

[image: This is my stocks_table]

Comment: Can you show the code you have so far so others can build on your code.

Comment: Please see https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-a-minimal-reproducible-example-for-a-very-simple-sql-query

Comment: So you want a query to update the remaining quantity in various stocks, choosen by expiration priority, given the id of the product and the quantity bought .

Comment: @user1767316 Yes sir.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is code below the solution ([fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=1a01e700c3f8ba2e315177ad52de6625))?

```
with cte as(
select * from(
    select *, case when cumulsum <= TotalRequiredQuantity then 0 else cumulsum-TotalRequiredQuantity end NewQuantity 
     from(
       select *, 20 TotalRequiredQuantity,/*Set valid quantitity*/
          sum(stock_quantity) over(partition by item_code order by stock_expired) cumulsum
       from stocks_table
       where item_code = 'I0015'/*Set valid item_code*/
    )q
)q1
where stock_quantity>=NewQuantity)

update stocks_table st
join cte on st.id=cte.id
set st.stock_quantity = NewQuantity
```

without common table expression:

```
update stocks_table st
join(
  select * from(
    select *
    ,case when cumulsum <= TotalRequiredQuantity then 0 else cumulsum-TotalRequiredQuantity end NewQuantity 
     from(
       select *, 20 TotalRequiredQuantity,/*Set valid quantitity*/
          sum(stock_quantity) over(partition by item_code order by stock_expired) cumulsum
       from stocks_table
       where item_code = 'I0015'/*Set valid item_code*/
    )q
  )q1
  where stock_quantity>=NewQuantity
)cte on st.id=cte.id
set st.stock_quantity = NewQuantity
```

Comment: Sir I got this error I don't know why. SQL Error (1064): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'cte as( select * from(     select *, case when cumulsum <= TotalRequiredQuanti' at line 1. I'm using HeidiSQL

Comment: This solution applicable for MySQL 8.0+

Comment: Thanks, sir, I think the query is correct but when I test in Heidi SQL, I got an error in specifically in a partition.

Comment: Sir @Nick, This is my problem, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60576264/query-for-update-stock-quantity-in-transaction, Can you please give me some idea on how do I convert this into GROUP BY. THANK YOU!